# phpmyadmin, how to update table,field support full-text search with aql sentence?

Tags: php, sql, full-text-search, phpmyadmin

I have a database, there already has 300,000+ rows in it. Now I want add a full-text search function? I want to update my table field `myassac.title` support a full-text search. How to control in the `phpmyadmin` with sql sentence? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the `myassac` table is a MyISAM type table (InnoDB does NOT support fulltext indexes), then it's a simple matter of

```
ALTER TABLE myassac ADD FULLTEXT (title);
```

Comment: Will InnoDB ever support fulltext indexes?

Comment: Notice that MySQL supported full-text index in the InnoDB tables since version 5.6.
[Tutorial Link Here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/activating-full-text-searching.aspx)